# How to make tcsh command correction more sensible?

Tags: command-line, shell, tcsh

tcsh command correction (the behavior enabled by `set correct = cmd`) has an annoying "feature" that I'd like to disable: if I execute a program, but have another program with the same name "nearby", it attempts to correct my (valid) command.  To be more concrete, say I have two executables located as follows:

```
/my/working/path/exec.sh
/my/working/path/subdir/exec.sh
```

Now I run the following:

```
cd /my/working/path/subdir
./exec.sh
```

tcsh will prompt `CORRECT>../exec.sh (y|n|e|a)?`

I don't want to disable command correction entirely; I just want to prevent it from triggering in this case in which it is obviously not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible with `set correct = cmd` enabled in tcsh, and according to the [tcsh Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh):

> Beware: spelling correction is not guaranteed to work the way one
>   intends, and is provided mostly as an experimental feature.
>   Suggestions and improvements are welcome.

So you might want to submit an "enhancement request" via the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/issues).